# Can anyone identify these headers?

Tags: pins, breadboard

I'm very new to the Arduino platform and micro-controller projects in general, which is why I'm still learning about all the parts needed for circuit creation. There is one particular part that I would need for my current project but I'm having troubles figuring out what exactly this "thing" is ...

Please take a look at this picture: https://i2.wp.com/makezine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/rolljam-hardware.jpg?fit=929%2C724

I need to know, please, what exactly these dual row female headers are called that are placed right to the Teensy board and are holding the two CC1101 units (so I can find them on Amazon or in other shops). 
Obviously, they are spanning the gap on the breadboard but is there something you can buy like this? Or are these common dual row headers that have had their pins bent and put into single row headers? 
I can't quite tell. The whole thing looks custom made though (to me it even looks like some hot glue was used, but I might be entirely wrong about that).

^^ And if my assumption is right, what might be the purpose of doing this? From my understanding this would create a full row for the power (instead of having two shorter rows), which the gap on the breadboard is meant to prevent?!

Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: https://www.creatroninc.com/category/idc-ribbon-breakout-board/prototyping/breadboard-adapter

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I know that you can buy these things (but I still can't shake the feeling that the ones on the picture are custom made). I would still like to know, please, what might be the purpose of bridging the gap with one of these? Why not just use common dual row headers on one half of the breadboard?

Comment: All the rows on one side of the breadboard are tied together. Without such an adapter you can't access each pin individually.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. You are right. Please see my previous comment to the answer below. Thank you.

Comment: Btw: There is another slightly different version of this device that makes it more clear what you mean --> http://www.popsci.com/sites/popsci.com/files/styles/large_1x_/public/_rolljam2-web.jpg?itok=9pmUGcrd If there's just one row of pins like on the two RF433 modules, you can put either one on one half of the breadboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the pic, it looks like a 2x16 female header, PCB mount, with the pins bent outward and soldered to some male header pins.

I think they do this to provide mating sockets for the 2x5 male pins on the CC11001s that can be hooked up to a breadboard.

You could avoid this by prototyping on something like "stripboard' or 'Veroboard' like [https://www.amazon.com/Soldering-Prototype-Printed-Circuit-Stripboard/dp/B019Q14GRQ/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B019Q14GRQ) and cutting/soldering a few traces where appropriate.

Or you could use a small chunk of stripboard tor protoboard to do the adapting from the 2x5 at 0.1" centers, to 2x5 on 0.1"x0.4" centers.

Comment: Yes, these headers are there so all the pins of the CC1101 units can be connected to the breadboard. The one thing I'm curious about is: why do it exactly this way? Why bridge the gap? Why not just use common dual row headers on one half of the breadboard? Since the creator of the device on the picture obviously put in some effort to create these custom made "bridge", I can only assume that there must be some purpose behind it. That's what I need to find out next. But you guys already answered my initial question. Thank you for that!

Comment: Edit: Just saw Ignacio's comment above. That seems to be the right answer. I understand now why this "bridge" was necessary for the CC1101s.

Comment: Ah, it seems that you are missing the fact that each set of 5 holes on one half of the breadboard are shorted together with a metal clip.  If you do as you say, you will short the C1101's pin 1 to pin 2, pin 3 to pin 4, etc....  You need to bridge the gap to break those connections.